# Nodejs database connection, connection error, cant find port

Tags: sql, node.js, database

I am trying to build a database connection with a nodejs for the first time. everything went well but when i run it i get a connection error: port for LP12 not found in servername. i checked the port in the sql configuration manager and it is default on 1433. How can i check if it is communicating with another port? Do you know how i can solve this problem?

Here is my code:
    var sql = require("mssql");

```
var dbConfig = {
server: "localhost\\VMB-LP12",
database: "SmmsData",
user: "",
password: "",
port: 1433
};

function getEmp(){
var conn = new sql.Connection(dbConfig);
var req = new sql.Request(conn);

conn.connect(function (err) {
if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
}
req.query("SELECT * FROM SysteemSensorInfo", function (err, recordset) {
if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
    }
else{
    console.log(recordset);
}
conn.close();
});

});

}

getEmp();
```

Comment: What error you are getting??

Comment: ConnectionError: Port for VMB-LP12 not found in ServerName; VMB-LP12; InstanceName; SQLEXPRESS;

Comment: leave port as empty

Comment: If i leave the port empty i get the same error

Answer (score 0):

I needed to create a login with an SQL authentication. You can not leave them empty. It started working when i filled my user name and password in from my sql authentication account.